# load dynamic content inside of the html page

Tags: jquery

I just created one `footer` content in `.js` page now I need to append that content for a class in a page,But some syntax error in dynamically created footer.I dont know how to create it dynamically.
Please any sugesstion?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var footer="<footer class='subFooter col-lg-12 col-md-12'>"
        "<div class='col-lg-12 col-md-12' style='padding-top:35px;'>"
            "<p style='display:inline;color:#fff'>@ xxxxx Limited</p>"
            "<img src='images/aaa.png'  class='pull-right'>"    
            "<img src='images/bbb.png'  class='pull-right'>"    
        "</div>"
    </footer>";
    $('#footer').append(footer);
});
```

This footer only I need to load in `#footer`

Comment: you're not concatenating the strings `"<footer> ...." + "<div> ...."`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to concatenate these strings (added the `+` characters at the end of the lines and the missing quotes before the `</footer>` closing):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var footer = "<footer class='subFooter col-lg-12 col-md-12'>" +
     "<div class='col-lg-12 col-md-12' style='padding-top:35px;'>" +
       "<p style='display:inline;color:#fff'>@ 2023 by Camion Ligistics Limited</p>" +
       "<img src='images/Artboard 21 copy.png' id='twitterIcon' class='pull-right'>" +
       "<img src='images/Artboard 21.png' id='fbIcon' class='pull-right'>" +
     "</div>" +
    "</footer>";
  $('#footer').append(footer);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="footer"></div>
```

If you have multiple `footer`s you want to use a class instead of an id:

```
 <div class="footer"></div>
```

And then in the JavaScript side:

```
 $(".footer").append(...);
```

Comment: @AlivetoDie Thanks! :)

Comment: Heh thanks.But, am using `#footer` 5places in my code,its appending only once.

Comment: its a nav-tabs..for each tab i need to load that footer.what to do?

Comment: @krish  your tabs will open new pages?

Comment: no complete code is in a single page only.. i have used multiple `div`.Using `id` am loading the `div`.For each tab separate `div`.

Comment: @krish Sorry, can you detail that? If you have multiple footers (I assume that one is visible at the time) you should not use `id="footer"` but use a class instead. The id should be unique in the document.

Answer (score 1):

```
var footer="<footer class='subFooter col-lg-12 col-md-12'>" + 
        "<div class='col-lg-12 col-md-12' style='padding-top:35px;'>" +
            "<p style='display:inline;color:#fff'>@ 2023 by Camion Ligistics Limited</p>" +
            "<img src='images/Artboard 21 copy.png' id='twitterIcon' class='pull-right'>"   +
            "<img src='images/Artboard 21.png' id='fbIcon' class='pull-right'>" +
        "</div>"+
    "</footer>";
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the working code. Your code had double quotes which are not needed. Instead have the entire HTML in one-line. If you take them in next line with double quotes than you need to append those with + sign.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var footerHTML = "<footer class='subFooter col-lg-12 col-md-12'><div class='col-lg-12 col-md-12' style='padding-top:35px;'><p style='display:inline;color:#fff'>@ 2023 by Camion Ligistics Limited</p><img src='images/Artboard 21 copy.png' id='twitterIcon' class='pull-right'><img src='images/Artboard 21.png' id='fbIcon' class='pull-right'></div></footer>";
  $('#footer').html(footerHTML);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="footer"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, **if you can use ES6**, you can use the multi-line string approach, for better clarity:

```
$(document).ready(() => {
  var footer = `
    <footer class="subFooter col-lg-12 col-md-12">
      <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12" style="padding-top:35px;">
        <p style="display:inline;color:#fff">@ 2023 by Camion Ligistics Limited</p>
        <img src="images/Artboard 21 copy.png" id="twitterIcon" class="pull-right">
        <img src="images/Artboard 21.png" id="fbIcon" class="pull-right">
      </div>
    </footer>`;

  $('#footer').append(footer);
});
```

This also allows you to use double quotes for more familiar html.